# Verb for 'putting to sleep'

Tags: word-request

Is there a verb for "putting someone to sleep"?
For example, how would one replace the `....` with a single word in the following sentence:

> If you are tossing and turning and you just can't fall asleep, then I'll sing a song to .... you`?

Upon [googling](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/put_to_sleep.html) a [bit](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/putting%20to%20sleep), I found some verbs like `sedate`, `muffle`, `benumb`, but they seem to have a slightly negative connotation to them.
 What will be a good, neutral kind of a verb for "putting someone to sleep"?

Comment: If the context is *caring for babies*, consider [settle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/settle), definition 3.5.

Comment: This would be a good question if it asked for the most natural way to express the idea.  Unfortunately, because you ask for only a single word, and because it has to fill in the blank in your sentence, the only possible answers are less natural-sounding, making this a worse question than it should be.

Comment: @snailplane - It filling the blank is not a requirement, I just added the statement for an example as to what I was looking for (and as an insight as to how the question struck me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single word you may be looking for is

> **lull** - calm or send to sleep, typically with soothing sounds or movements
>
> I'll sing a song to **lull** you to sleep.

as in **lull**aby.

Comment: Correct, although I don't think anyone would use just the single word.  "Lull you to sleep" is the idiomatic expression.

Comment: So I can say something like "I lulled him by singing him a lullaby."? Or in fact fill the blank in the sentence mentioned in the question by the word `lull`? Will that be correct?

Comment: The phrase would be "I **lulled** him **to sleep** by singing him a lullaby.", "**lulled to sleep**" is the idiomatic expression.

Comment: Thanks, although I was asking only about the grammatical correctness.